# HIGHCHARTS Gantt / X axis Displaying YEAR / QUARTERS / MONTHS

Tags: highcharts

we are trying to create 3 X header lines, one containing the years, other the quarters and the last one containing months... something similar to this:
[image]

As you can see in the image above, we have 2 lines, one with years, the other one is quarters (3 months), we would like to add an additional line below each quarter with the months, our code looks like:
[image]

NOTE: As 3 months (quarter) is not something that has its label automatically, we created a label using the formatter.

Now when we try to add a third row like this:
[image]

What we get is something unexpected... years work right, while quarters are now extended like years, and the list of months is correct as follow:

[image]

The following image should give you a better idea of what we would like to achieve:
[image]

Thank you for any help you may bring. My code link is below.

Comment: MY CODE LINK https://jsfiddle.net/sipi_intel/s14qxe6w/28/

Answer (score 0):

Note  this line in header it's called the x-axis, is an array of configuration objects. You can use [xAxis.tickInterval](https://api.highcharts.com/gantt/xAxis.tickInterval) to set the tick interval in axis units for each object.

In [dateTimeLabelFormats](https://api.highcharts.com/gantt/xAxis.dateTimeLabelFormats), you can change the unit name to the required one.

```
  xAxis: [{
    tickInterval: 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24, // Days
    labels: {
      format: '{value:%e. %b.}',
      style: {
        fontSize: '8px'
      }
    },
    units: [
      [
        'day',
        [2]
      ]
    ]
  }, {
    tickInterval: 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 30, // Month
/*     labels: {
      format: '{value:%b}',
    }, */
    min: Date.UTC(2014, 3, 17),
    max: Date.UTC(2015, 11, 0),
    currentDateIndicator: true,
    units: [
      [
        'month',
        [3]
      ]
    ],
    dateTimeLabelFormats: {
      month: {
        list: ['Quater']
      }
    }
  }, {
    tickInterval: 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 365, // Year
    labels: {
      format: '{value:%Y}',
      style: {
        fontSize: '15px'
      }
    },
    linkedTo: 1
  }],
```

Live demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/w3nb4oqj/

Comment: Thank you @Sebastian-Hajdus... it was year / Quarters / Months not days but your demo was enough for me to continue, now I have another problem, the labels are shown erratically, not overlapping, not showing, can't be rotated... I will open another question, thank you!

Comment: Please [example](https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/w3nb4oqj/1/) with converted version to months, the demo only presented the main idea.